# Cucumber table: changing

Tags: ruby, cucumber

What I am trying to do is iterate over a list of columns, run a function against that column, save the result, the using .diff to compare expected results with actual results.  That way I guess a pretty table of green and red depending on how the test completed.

So I have a table that looks like the following:

```
  |     COLUMN_NAME         |     result |
  |     RecordNum           |     pass   |
  |     MasterCompanyTicker |     pass   |
```

A sql script is executed against each column name, returning 'pass' or 'fail' depending on the outcome.  The function is as follows:

```
Then(/^these columns are expected to be not null$/) do |columns|
  # expected is an instance of Cucumber::Ast::Table
  WorkTable.logger.info title_line('Columns cannot be null')

  sql = File.readlines(File.join(ENV['ms_home'],'db','scripts','test','pass_or_fail_template.sql'))
  sql = (sql.map {|l| l.strip}).join(' ')

  results = columns.clone
  results.hashes.each {|row|
    st = sprintf(sql,"#{WorkTable.table_name}","#{WorkTable.table_name}.#{row['COLUMN_NAME']}")
    row['result'] = WorkTable.connection.select_all(st.encode('utf-8')).first['result']
  }
  columns.diff!(results,surplus_row: false)
end
```

The sql script is running correctly; there is one that returns the string 'fail'.  So I am expecting row['result'] to be 'fail'.  If I do pp right after assignment, I indeed see that row['result'] == 'fail'.

```
{"COLUMN_NAME"=>"TermDate", "result"=>"fail"}
```

However, if I do "pp results" against the whole table after the "results.hashes" block, it is not 'fail'.  It is its original value, 'pass'.

```
|     TermDate            |     pass   |
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  I thought this was an ingenious way of collecting all the results in on swoop, the comparing them using table.diff.  I've seen other posts along these lines and tried following the advice, but it doesn't work for me.

Your time and consideration is appreciated,
dvn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Lord, I am so sorry.  I have the solution after I posted the question (with a truncated subject line.)  The solution is as follows:

```
  results = []
  columns.hashes.each {|row|
    st = sprintf(sql,"#{WorkTable.table_name}","#{WorkTable.table_name}.#{row['COLUMN_NAME']}")
    results << {
        'COLUMN_NAME' => row['COLUMN_NAME'],
        'result' => WorkTable.connection.select_all(st.encode('utf-8')).first['result']
    }
  }

  columns.diff!(results,surplus_row: false)
```

I was trying to diff a table against another table.  That is not the correct thing to do.  I need to diff a table against an array of hashes.  When I do that correctly, I get the following output:

```
   | ActiveDate          | pass   |
   | TermDate            | pass   |  <<
   | TermDate            | fail   |  <<
   | create_user         | pass   |
   | create_dt           | pass   |
```

That is what I was looking for.

Sorry to bother. Hopefully this helps someone else.
dvn